# javascript array reference and callback function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference, callback

The stuff I don´t understand I find it rather long to explain so please bear with me. I have the following incude js in my page:

```
var include = (function(){
    var exports = {}
    var test = function(url){
        var result = [];
        $.ajax(url).then(function(data){
            result = data.form.records;  // assume data.form.records valid
            console.log(result) // displays correctly Array [Object,Object] 
        });
        return result;
    }
    exports.test = test;
    return exports
})();
```

then from the page i make the following call (assum that some_url is valid)

```
var array = include.test(some_url);
```

later i have a event ( some button click ) that will use the values in the array

```
input.on('click',function(){
   console.log(array) // 2
});
```

My problem is that when the event occurs the array variable is still VOID ,
The console.log // 2 displays Array [ ]....

i know my test function returns immediately so the immediate value of array variable is Array [ ] , but by the time the input.click gets called , the then() callback would already have been executed so the array itself should be modified .After all array is a reference ...

Any suggestion ? I don´t usually ask questions because most of the time i find the answers by searching but i already tried for a day. Maybe i have a lack of inspiration. Some help would be appreciated

Comment: you need to set the array inside the callback function (then(... )

Comment: Yeah, K3N is right, AJAX is asynch, return is synch the way you coded it, doesn't really work using both asynch and synch.

Comment: Just wondering if it's really that hard to indent your code properly and put semicolons where they belonw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array` is referring to an empty array, but in the ajax callback you have `result = data.form.records;` which is assigning a new array to `result` instead of updating the array referred by `array` that is why even after the console logs the correct value for `result` array is referring to the initial empty array.

```
var include = (function() {
  var exports = {}
  var test = function(url) {
    var result = [];
    $.ajax(url).then(function(data) {
      result.length = 0;//remove existing items from the array
      result.push.apply(result, data.form.records);//copy the items from the records to the result array instead of assigning a new value
      console.log(result) // displays correctly Array [Object,Object] 
    });
    return result;
  }
  exports.test = test;
  return exports
})();
```

Comment: I have changed references and didn't even noticed it ... thank you for showing me that result = data.form.records; was the error i had in my code